# Converting 3 bytes into signed integer in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, int, byte

I'm trying to convert 3 bytes to signed integer (Big-endian) in C#.

I've tried to use `BitConverter.ToInt32` method, but my problem is what value should have the lats byte.

Can anybody suggest me how can I do it in different way?

I also need to convert 5 (or 6 or 7) bytes to signed long, is there any general rule how to do it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sign and Magnitude? Two's complement?

Comment: It's in two's complement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a last resort you could always shift+add yourself:

```
byte b1, b2, b3;

int r = b1 << 16 | b2 << 8 | b3;
```

Just swap b1/b2/b3 until you have the desired result.

On second thought, this will never produce negative values.
What result do you want when the msb >= 0x80 ?

---

Part 2, brute force sign extension:

```
    private static int Bytes2Int(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3)
    {
        int r = 0;
        byte b0 = 0xff;

        if ((b1 & 0x80) != 0) r |= b0 << 24;
        r |= b1 << 16;
        r |= b2 << 8;
        r |= b3;
        return r;
    }
```

I've tested this with:

```
      byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(p);
      int r = Bytes2Int(bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
      Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", p, r);
```

for several `p`.

Comment: ok, thank you for help. My finally solution is a bit different, but I also use the checking mechanism of most significant bit (b1 & 0x80) to  determine if number is positive or negative.

Comment: @vc.one, yes , thank for the edit. The `+` also needed `()` : `(b1 << 16) + ...`

Answer (score 4):

The last value should be 0 if it isn't set for a positive number, 256 for a negative.

To know what you should pass in, you can try converting it the other way:

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
int x = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answers here, there's a bit of a gotcha in that `Bitconverter.ToInt32()` will throw an `ArgumentException` if the array is less than `sizseof(int)` (4) bytes in size;

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.

Given an array less than `sizeof(int)` (4) bytes in size, you can compensate for left/right padding like so;

**Right-pad**

Results in positive `Int32` numbers

```
int intByteSize = sizeof(int);
byte[] padded = new byte[intByteSize];
Array.Copy(sourceBytes, 0, padded, 0, sourceBytes.Length);
sourceBytes = padded;
```

**Left-pad**

Results in negative `Int32` numbers, assuming non-zero value at byte index `sourceBytes.Length - 1`.

```
int intByteSize = sizeof(int);
byte[] padded = new byte[intByteSize];
Array.Copy(sourceBytes, 0, padded, intByteSize - sourceBytes.Length, sourceBytes.Length);
sourceBytes = padded;
```

Once padded, you can safely call `int myValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(sourceBytes, 0);`.