# VB Convert 3 bytes into an Int32 variable

Tags: vb.net

I searched similar solutions as:
[Converting 3 bytes into signed integer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104343/converting-3-bytes-into-signed-integer-in-c-sharp)

There are something different in VB.net. But, I am asking for the equivalent code.

Correct me if I am wrong:
(1) VB.net does no accept things like :

```
b0 << 24
```

it only does

```
b0 = b0 << 24
```

(2) For code of

```
r |= b1 << 16 ' This is in C#
```

Which operation is done first, << or |=?

(3) Referring to the linked thread, how to do

```
b0 = 0xff
```

in Vb.net?

Many thanks for giving help on the above 3 Qs.

Comment: You missed the extremely simple BitConverter version in the answer linked

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes, in VB you need to provide the variable first that you want to change the value of:

```
b0 = b0 << 24
```

(2) The << is done first, but this is C#.
In VB you don't have |= assignment operator. This is in C# and `x |= y` means the same as `x = x | y` and means the same as

```
x = x OR y
```

You need to use the last in VB as you do not have | or |= in VB.

(3) Not sure on what you mean here. But if you are asking on how to dimension the byte variable and assign the maximum value to it, you would use this:

```
Dim b0 As Byte = 255
```